# Node.js boolean variable not changing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, boolean

I have following code:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res)
    {
        /*
        connection is created with mysql
         */
        var success = true
        connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result)
        {
            success = false
        })
        connection.end()
        console.log(success)
    }
)
```

The output of this is `true`. How do I change the value of success from inside of connection.query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the code block in which `success` is redefined `success = false;` is "before" `console.log(result)` in terms of line numbers. It actually takes place after.
`connection.query()` is invoked with a function which will get invoked at a later time, after the query has completed.

There's at least 3 different ways to handle this.

the **callback style**
this is simply wrapping the code you want to execute in the `conn.query` anonymous function like so

```
app.post('/', function (req, res)
    {
        /*
        connection is created with mysql
        */
        var success = true;
        var callback = function(result) {
            success = result;
            console.log(success);
            connection.end()
        };

        connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result)
        {
            callback(result);
        });
    }
);
```

the **promise style**
if `conn.query()` returns returns a promise then you could do something like this:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res)
    {
        /*
        connection is created with mysql
        */
        var success = true;
        var callback = function(result) {
            success = result;
            console.log(success);
            connection.end()
        };

        connection.query(sql, [values]).then(callback);
    }
);
```

more info on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Also, if you're using the mysql driver for node, you can also use [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) to use promises.

the **await style** which operate more intuitively for those who aren't used to event-driven programming.  Assuming your `conn.query()` supports Promises, you could use `await` and it would look something like this:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res)
    {
        /*
        connection is created with mysql
        */
        var success = true;
        await connection.query(sql, [values], (result) => success = false);
        console.log(success);
        connection.end();
    }
);
```

more info on [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 1):

This is Async program, your `console.log()` statement is getting executed before the `connection.query` callback function. The Value of success is being altered inside the function.

You can test this by:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var success = true;
    connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result){
       success = false;
       console.log(success);
       // more code goes here
    });
    connection.end();
});
```

If you want to write mode code, that'll go inside the callback function, where the comment exist.

Welcome to Node.js ;)